# How to convert byte array into image without saving it into file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

How to convert byte array into image without using file in python?

```
#image to bytearray
with open("C:/Downloads/myimage.jpeg", "rb") as image:
    f = image.read()
    b = bytearray(f)
#bytearray to image
f = open('xyz.jpeg', 'wb')
f.write(bytearray(b))
f.close()
```

Comment: what is an "image" for you here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). First install it: `pip install Pillow`

```
import io
from PIL import Image

#image to bytearray
with open("C:/Downloads/myimage.jpeg", "rb") as image:
    f = image.read()
    b = bytearray(f)

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
image.show()
# image.save("C:/Downloads/myimage_new.jpeg", "JPEG")  # to save the image
```

Comment: When I am trying to send that image into chat bot code . I got : Object of type JpegImageFile is not JSON serializable. Error. How can we resolve this.

Comment: Go the the docs of your chatbot framework(or whatever you are using) and figure out how to send images to chatbot. Maybe you can send bytearray and chatbot will convert it to image.